# interface = popen('ifconfig | awk \'/eth0/ {print $1}\'').read()

Tags: python-3.x, mininet

Does anybody know about this Python script? What it does?

```
interface = popen('ifconfig | awk \'/eth0/ {print $1}\'').read()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ifconfig
```

Will print something like:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
...
```

this will be piped into `awk` which will match the line with `eth0` by using the pattern `/eth0/` and print the first field which will be `eth0` in this case.

`popen` reads the output from this shell script into Python.

So if you have an `eth0` interface `interface` will be `eth0` in Python, and if you don't have an `eth0` interface `interface` will be the empty string in Python.

So my guess is that it looks if `eth0` is present on the system and will use it as default if available.

Answer (score 0):

Both `ifconfig` and `awk` are standard Unix/Linux commands. (The `ifconfig` has a replacement already, but is still used quite often).

In the shell command `ifconfig | awk '/eth0/ {print $1}'` the former command prints information about system's network interfaces and the latter is a filter which prints only the first field (basically first word) from each record (i.e. text line here) matching the `eth0` literal string. The `awk` is a powerfull text processing tool. Its comprehensive  manual has a size of a small book.

This shell command has a Python wrapper that runs it in a separate process and reads the resulting output. `popen` must be imported from `os` if you want to try it.

`eth0` is the traditional name of the first ethernet interface. The result is probably this name maybe followed by a colon and a newline. Network aliases like `eth0:0` will be included as well. It works only on systems using a naming scheme where `eth0` is used. E.g. Linux used such interface names in the past, but a different and more predictable naming scheme is now standard.

That's all what it does. I don't know the intended usage, but personally I find the code not reliable and inefficient.